# Prepared Statement Error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, incompatibletypeerror

Recently just changed my statements in SQL to prepared statements for security reasons and here's what I came up with..

Unfortunately it's coming up with an **cannot find error** on the

```
"SELECT * FROM owner WHERE username = ? AND" + "password = ?;";
```

**The whole error:**

Cannot find symbol:
symbol: method prepareStatement(java.lang.String)
location: variable dbAccess of type HolidayExchange.DBAccess

I realise that it's finding a String when it should be a preparedstatement but this is how I always see it in examples etc.

I'm probably doing something idiotic but any help solving this would be really helpful!

The whole method:

DBAccess dbAccess = new DBAccess();

```
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM owner WHERE username = '?' AND"+
                " password = '?'";

        PreparedStatement ps = dbAccess.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1,u);
        ps.setString(2,p);

        ResultSet rs = dbAccess.executeQuery2(ps);
        User user = new User();
        while (rs.next()){
            user.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname"));
            user.setSurname(rs.getString("surname"));
            user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        }

        rs.close();
        dbAccess.close();

        if(user.getUsername().length()==0){
            return null;
        }else{
            return user;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}`
```

Comment: What is the full package name of DBAcces? Check if the javadoc shows whether it even supports "prepareStatement".

Comment: public DBAccess() throws ServletException {
        this.getConnection();
    }

Comment: Which refernces the getconnection() method, which just gets the connection to the database and 100% works.

Comment: Basically all the Database access is put into it's own class. The DBAccess() method being the public method which references the private method getConnection(). All it does is get the conneciton the DB. In this class there is also methods for specific execute queries and update queries.

Comment: Doesn't look like DBAccess has a public prepareStatement, which is what is being called.

Answer (score 2):

There is a space missing

```
      // becomes ANDpassword in the resulting string:
     "SELECT * FROM owner WHERE username = ? AND" + "password = ?;";
```

should be

```
     // space added before passsword:
     "SELECT * FROM owner WHERE username = ? AND" + " password = ?;";
```

Comment: oops, thanks for that was a bit stupid. Although the main issue is the incompatible types error

Comment: Also looks like you are binding the username and password in the wrong order. Don't think the semi-colon at the end of the statement is necessary, either.

Answer (score 0):

Always log ps.toString() before you exeute a query. This will let programmer know what query actually is been executed.

Also, PreparedStatement are not strings

Connection con = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/jdbctutorial","root","root");
PrepareStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

Comment: My DBaccess class handles all the DB connections. I'll paste in the new code to see what you think though.

I still get an error saying it cannot find symbol, though

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot find symbol: symbol: method prepareStatement(java.lang.String)
>   location: variable dbAccess of type HolidayExchange.DBAccess

This error message does not have anything to dot with ill-formatted SQL. It is a compile time error. HolidayExchange.DBAccess class does not have method named prepareStatement that takes java.lang.String as argument.

Your SQL is not validated (or evaluated) in compile time, so it cannot be reason for compile time errors. Once you get it to compile, you probably will find that after you remove single quotes that are around question marks, your query will work fine.

Comment: Ok, I have this method in my DB access class: `code` public ResultSet executeQuery2(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException { try { return ps.executeQuery(); } catch (SQLException e) { throw e; } } `code` I just assumed prepareStatement was a method in the PreparedStatement package to be honest.

Comment: Also wrote this method to try deal with it.. public ResultSet executeQuery2(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        try {
            return ps.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

Should i invoke these to use the PreparedStatement?

Comment: So you do not have method named prepareStatement that returns PreparedStatement and takes string as argument. Additionally, PreparedStatement is not a package, it is an interface.

Comment: Ok, I just assumed cause every examples uses prepareStatement as an argument. Could I use executequery2 as the method instead of prepareStatement?

Comment: To be able to make this method call: dbAccess.prepareStatement(sql) and get PreparedStatement returned, DBAccess class should have following method: public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) {//some implementation, return instance of PreparedStatement in the end }

Answer (score 0):

if you have the import `com.mysq.jdbc.*;` remove it and change it to 
import `java.sql.PreparedStatement;` hence vice versa, coz I think that it's either the PreparedStatement method that you are using is not suitable for the database you are connecting.

Answer (score -1):

For each question mark try putting single quotes around them.

```
 '?'
```

Comment: Really? Wouldn't that be asking the server to do implicit casting after you already specified the bind types? Don't think it is something I would do. Or I'm missing something here.

Comment: I agree with Glen, pretty certain you don't need ''